# ImportError: No module named fabric

Tags: python, python-2.7, mysql-fabric

I am new to mysql fabric. I am getting the following error:

```
root@ajith-System-Product-Name:/home/ajith# mysqlfabric
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/mysqlfabric", line 33, in <module>
from mysql.fabric import (
ImportError: No module named fabric
```

I installed `mysql-connector-python_2.1.3`, `mysql-utilities_1.5.6`, and `python2.7`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `from` statement should use `mysqlfabric`, not `mysql.fabric`, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Hi mech thanks for the reply, iam not sure about that but my issue solved when i update ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04