# ImportError: No module named fabric when run mysqlfabric command

Tags: mysql, mysql-fabric

My VM is using Ubuntu 14.04.
I followed the official manual to install `MySql Fabric`:

- First, install Connector/Python GA
- Next, install MySQL Utilities 1.5.6

However, when I tried to test the `mysqlfabric help` command, it threw error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/mysqlfabric", line 33, in <module>
from mysql.fabric import (
ImportError: No module named fabric
```

Based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35474364/importerror-no-module-named-fabric), after upgrading Ubuntu from 15.04, the problem can be resolved, but I want to run `fabric` on Ubuntu 14.04.

I tried to re-installed `Connector/Python`, `MySQL Utilities`, also checked compatibility with Ubuntu version 14.04, searched on the Internet & SO for similar problems. But still cannot resolve the issue.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what is the problem with installing using `.deb` file.

But after many (painful) tries, I figured out that re-installing [`MySQL Utilities` from source code](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/mysql-utils-install-source.html) can resolve the issue.